# How to change regex?

Tags: c#, regex

```
private static readonly Regex FileDirectoryRegex = new Regex(@"^[^""\\:|<>*?]*\/{0,1}$");

if (folderName.EndsWith("/") || folderName.Contains("//"))
{
    throw new ArgumentException());
}
```

How to add last `if` statement validation to my `FileDirectoryRegex` ?

Comment: Did you mean `FileDirectoryRegex.IsMatch(folderName)`?

Comment: No, I want to change my regex. It must include last `if`. I don't want to have both of them: `if` and `regex`

Comment: I think you need `@"^(?!.*//)[^""\\:|<>*?]*(?<!/)$"`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It works! Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can merge the `if` conditions to your regex as follows:

```
@"^(?!.*//)[^""\\:|<>*?]*(?<!/)$"
   ^^^^^^^^              ^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo at RegexStorm](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E(%3F!.*%2F%2F)%5B%5E%5Cn%22%5C%5C%3A%7C%3C%3E*%3F%5D*(%3F%3C!%2F%5Cr%3F)%5Cr%3F%24&i=http%3A%2F%2Ftest.com%0D%0Ac%3A%2FSome%2Ffolder%2Ffile.txt%0D%0A%2Fmore%2Fnot-here%2F%0D%0A%2Fmore%2Fhere%0D%0Abad%2F%2Ftext%0D%0Amatch-it-now&o=m) (a little modified there since it is a multiline string demo)

The `(?!.*//)` is a negative lookahead that will fail the match if the engine finds `//` somewhere after 0+ chars other than a newline (`.*`) and `(?<!/)` is a negative lookbehind that will fail the match if there is a `/` right before the end of string.

**HOWEVER**, lots of users say it is bad practice to cram all conditions into 1 regex, please consider choosing the more readable approach (the one you have now, split the conditions).